# Safest way to unwrap optionals

Tags: swift, api, optimization, error-handling, option-type

I finished coding my app and now is time to add safety features to prevent crashes. I didn't implement a correct `nil` handling yet, testing revealed a few crashes from fetching no data from the API.

My structure is a little complex and I lost myself trying to implement the security thing so I would like you guys fresh opinion and your ultimate safest way of dealing with `nil`. I took my code a few steps back for you to review.

The code is *complete* for you to try in a `Playground`

Here is the `struct`:

```
struct Ripple : Decodable {
        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case raw = "RAW" }
        let raw : RippleRAW
    }

    struct RippleRAW : Decodable {
        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case xrp = "XRP" }
        let xrp : RippleCURRENCIES
    }

    struct RippleCURRENCIES : Decodable {
        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case usd = "USD"
            case rub = "RUB"
        }
        let usd : RippleUSD?
        let rub : RippleRUB?
    }

    struct RippleUSD : Decodable {
        let price : Double
        let percentChange24h : Double

        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case price = "PRICE"
            case percentChange24h = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            percentChange24h = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .percentChange24h)
            do {
                price = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .price)
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, _) {
                let stringValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price)
                price = Double(stringValue)!
            }
        }
    }

    struct RippleRUB : Decodable {
        let price : Double
        let percentChange24h : Double

        private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
            case price = "PRICE"
            case percentChange24h = "CHANGEPCT24HOUR"
        }
        init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
            let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
            percentChange24h = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .percentChange24h)
            do {
                price = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .price)
            } catch DecodingError.typeMismatch(_, _) {
                let stringValue = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .price)
                price = Double(stringValue)!
            }
        }
    }
```

Here I am fetching and decoding the data from the API:

```
enum MyErrorXRP : Error {
        case FoundNil(String)
    }

class RippleInfo : NSObject {

        func fetchRippleInfo(forCurrency currency: String, _ completion: @escaping (Ripple?, Error?) -> Void) {
            let url = URL(string: "https://min-api.cryptocompare.com/data/pricemultifull?fsyms=XRP&tsyms=\(currency)")!
            let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let data = data else { return }
                do {
                    if let rippleData = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Ripple.self, from: data) {
                        completion(rippleData, nil)
                    } else {
                        throw MyErrorXRP.FoundNil("rippleData")
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            task.resume()
        }
    }
```

And these are the calling functions, used in the app to update labels:

```
func rippleDataUpdate() {
        if MainViewController.currencyRUB == true {
            RippleInfo().fetchRippleInfo(forCurrency: "RUB", { (ripple, error) in
                if ripple != nil {
                    print("ok ripple rub")
                } else {
                    print("notworking")
                }
                self.updateRippleUI(with: ripple!)
            })
        }
    }

    func updateRippleUI(with rippleInfo: Ripple) {
            MainViewController.rippleDoublePrice = Double((rippleInfo.raw.xrp.rub?.price)!)
            MainViewController.xrpPercent = Double((rippleInfo.raw.xrp.rub?.percentChange24h)!)

    }
```

All of this code is contained in a `MainViewController` for it to run in `Playground` with these variables:

```
class MainViewController : UIViewController {

    static var rippleDoublePrice : Double = 0
    static var xrpPercent : Double = 0
    static var currencyRUB : Bool = true
}
```

I have a few ideas about what to do but the fact that I need to be able to fetch different things through the same struct confuses me a little.

What is your opinion?

Comment: `self.updateRippleUI(with: ripple!)` boom goes the dynamite

Comment: Do you advise `@escaping (Ripple, Error?)` with `self.updateRippleUI(with: ripple)` ?

Comment: Another common error shows that you need to take a deeper look at how optionals work is the use of optional chaining with a force unwrap at the end. `(rippleInfo.raw.xrp.rub?.price)!`

Comment: So as already note in comments by @Alexander don't force unwrap your optionals and/or check it agains nil. Add a guard statement to safely unwrap your optional and return in case of failure.  `guard let ripple  = ripple else { print(error ?? ""); return }`

Comment: Another crucial point is the use of if let try? inside a do try catch. You should use try and throw the error inside your catch. Btw no need to unwrap rippleData it is optional and the object returned will be already unwrapped when using do try catch. Btw it is not `Data` type `let ripple = try JSONDecoder().decode(Ripple.self, from: data)` `completion(ripple, nil)`

Comment: Note that inheriting from `NSObject` there is pointless. You should use a `struct` instead of a `class`. `== true` is redundant when using using conditional with `Bool` types

Comment: I'm kind of confused, any chance you might show me how it would look like in code?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
func rippleDataUpdate() {
            if MainViewController.currencyRUB == true {
                RippleInfo().fetchRippleInfo(forCurrency: "RUB", { (ripple, error) in

                guard ripple != nil else {
                    return
                }

                self.updateRippleUI(with: ripple!)


                })
            }
        }


     func updateRippleUI(with rippleInfo: Ripple) {
         if let price = rippleInfo.raw.xrp.rub?.price {
            MainViewController.rippleDoublePrice = Double(price)
         }

        if let percent = rippleInfo.raw.xrp.rub?.percentChange24h {
            MainViewController.xrpPercent = Double(percent)
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! In that case `ripple!` is safe because you checked for nil right? What would you do to `func fetchRippleInfo`? I'm confused by what other answers gave me.